# What purpose does this receive statement fullfil in this judge function?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I recently started learning Erlang from https://learnyousomeerlang.com
in this chapter [errors and processes](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes#naming-processes), I understood what the program does and how it executes but I'm unable to figure out what's the purpose of this receive the statement in judge function when and how will it be called?

From What I understand if tuple pattern matches with Pid and atom it returns an atom. How will i send message to receive inside judge?

```
  start_critic() ->
  spawn(?MODULE, critic, []).

judge(Pid, Band, Album) ->
  Pid ! {self(), {Band, Album}},
  receive 
    {Pid, Criticism} -> Criticism
  after 2000 ->
    timeout
  end.

critic() ->
  receive
    {From, {"Rage Against the Turing Machine", "Unit Testify"}} ->
      From ! {self(), "They are great!"};
    {From, {"System of a Downtime", "Memoize"}} ->
      From ! {self(), "They're not Johnny Crash but they're good."};
    {From, {"Johnny Crash", "The Token Ring of Fire"}} ->
      From ! {self(), "Simply incredible."};
    {From, {_Band, _Album}} ->
      From ! {self(), "They are terrible!"}
  end,
  critic().
```

Output

```
c(linkmon).
{ok,linkmon}

Critic = linkmon:start_critic().
<0.109.0>

linkmon:judge(Critic, "Genesis", "The Lambda Lies Down on Broadway").
"They are terrible!"

linkmon:judge(Critic, "Genesis", "A trick of the Tail Recursion").
"They are terrible!"

linkmon:judge(Critic, "Johnny Crash", "The Token Ring of Fire").
"Simply incredible."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Pid ! ...` sends a message to the critic. The critic will then send a response via one of the `From ! ...` lines. The `receive` in the `judge` function waits for said response and then simply returns the string contained in the response.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so stupid now, how did I miss that. :)